# Saving base64 image to blob container in Pyspark

Tags: image, pyspark, binary, base64, databricks

I have dataframe with one column containing `base64` strings representing images, taken from jpg files read from `Blob Container`. Here simple code for getting it:

```
img_df = spark.read.format("binaryFile").load("/mnt/pictures")
proc_df = img_df.select(base64(col("content")).alias('encoded'))
proc_df.write.mode("overwrite").format("text").save('/mnt/pictures_text')
```

Now I want to save it as a `image`/`binaryFile` by loading text and decoding:

```
img_df = spark.read.format("text").load("/mnt/pictures_text")
proc_df = img_df.select(unbase64(col("value")).alias('decoded'))
proc_df.write.format("binaryFile").save("/mnt/pictures_text/copy")
```

It works fine until saving. I got exception that: `Write is not supported for binary file data source`. I also tried other ways, including e.g `image` mode. Is there any other way for saving it with `jpg` format? I can have images only as a `base64` string in starting point.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not supported. The workaround would be to use UDF to write individual records or `.foreach`